# R time change and filter

Tags: r

I want to change my time like this 11:30:00.000000 into 11:30:00. And I want filter time from 11:30:00 to 14:30:00 in data.frame. I used the following code

```
mytime=as.POSIXlt(msn$Time.L.)
fd<-subset(msn,msn$Time.L. < 14:30:00.000000 and 11:30:00.000000 )
```

Comment: And? What is the problem? Any error message? (I guess you received one).

Comment: Try `str1 <- '11:30:00.000000';
 sub('\\..*', '', str1)`